# GitHub Markdown Warning and Note all on one line

Tags: github, markdown

When I am editing my README.md files in a GitHub repo I am trying to add Warnings and/or Notes using this format:

```markdown
> **Note**
> This is a note

> **Warning**
> This is a warning
```

As recommended here:

https://github.com/community/community/discussions/16925

However, it appears like this:

[image: Warning example]

All the text is on one line.

Anyone know why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was provided by [@Mohammed Albushra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21352856/mohammed-albushra) in one of the comments below:

```markdown
> **Note**  <- put two spaces here
> This is a note
```

And now they appear as intended!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I hope it helps.

```markdown
> **Note**
>
> This is a note

> **Warning**
>
> This is a warning
```

or you can add two spaces at the end of the line after `**Warning**` and `**Note**`

Comment: I have tried this and it does work, but there is now an empty line between the "Warning" and the message. Better than the same line, but not quite as nice as it is supposed to work. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome, i have also been brought attention to this just now try adding two spaces at the end of the warning line it will look just like you want I believe.

Comment: Yea that work. Why does that work?

Comment: looks like it's markdown syntax